# Release Agent Demands in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to set demands for the *release* of a project in Visual Studio Team Services. This release has additional demands that I would like to specify when picking a build agent.

I can set demands for a *build* in VSTS easily, but I can't find anywhere that specifies where you can set a demand for a release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random clicking got me there a few minutes after posting this. When viewing your release tasks, there is a tiny link saying "Run on Agent".

[image]

If you click this link, then it opens a side panel where you can specify demands.

[image]